# How generic TS works in this instance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have come across the following code online and I am a bit confused as to how the `T` generic plays a part.

The code looks like the following:

```
interface TeamProps<T> {
   name: keyof T & string;
   league: string;
}

function Team<T>({
   name,
   league
}: TeamProps<T>){
   .... React component
}
```

and the component is used like this:

```
<Team name="Liverpool" league="Premier League" />
```

I can't see where `T` is being defined and where `keyof T` comes from.

Can anyone help explain this, or let me know if more information is required.

Comment: `T` is inferred from the value of `name`, which must be both a string _and_ a key of T, so in this case T is `{ Liverpool: any }`. Without a bit more context it's hard to say _why_ that generic is being used, though.

Comment: is `T` also not `PremierLeague`?

Comment: No, as you can see from `TeamProps` there's no connection between the `league` property and `T` - only the `name` property is required to be `keyof T`.

Comment: there isn't really any more code/context, so do you think it is a case of adding the generic unnecessarily or is it adding any value? Is it adding any more safety?

Comment: Presumably `T` _isn't_ being inferred in actual usage, and represents an object that maps team names to some other data - in that case, this prevents using a team name that doesn't exist in that mapping. But you haven't even shared a link to what you're looking at, so it's hard to say.

Comment: it is being inferred, there is no mapping going on. But yeah understandable it's hard to know without sharing a link

Answer (score 1):

It depends how `Team` is called/constructed.

Consider this example:

```js
import React from 'react'

interface TeamProps<T> {
  name: keyof T & string;
  league: string;
}

function Team<T>({
  name,
  league
}: TeamProps<T>) {
  return null
}

const ok = <Team<{ age: 42 }> name='age' league='League' /> // ok

const error = <Team<{ age: 42 }> name='Name' league='League' /> // expected error

const error2 = <Team<{ 2: 42 }> name={2} league='League' /> // expected error, keys should be string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAFVRAAUcwBnAHiYD44Ab1Jw4lFCCQAuOAGskATwiZmcAGRwuMKFQDmAblFwANqj0BXGVp36jAX3KYLlDMAiVmrPvwAUIsQkpABpjMxRLJFJ7WRZJDghuHwBKYWMiGAsoT0oLExNo8jQPbTgIOTgAXjg%20byE4COsAFgAmOHtBIKRK-Eb8U3MrHoAZQaR%20gHpBCYmyuSKS%20FocKCqauJAeesbZVvbOyW78ADlD-vDIkbHJ6dmkAA8wJAwkABM4ZegFylLPqDbqrVJFs4C1dm0OuJDpUhC17AMIkN8KNEeM4FN0XdHs8aO8-sF5EouFoABYQPLvABGjG0ukoeiAA)

If `Team` is called in the same way as you did in your example, without explicit generic argument in `Team<{ age: 42 }>`, then using `T` does not make any sense.

Comment: yeah I thought maybe if it was called differently, but it's called the same way as in my example above `<Team name="Liverpool" league="Premier League" />`

Comment: @peterflanagan then, it doe not make any sense ,It even make harm